# Best way to traverse a STL map(set/multiset) while the element might be removed and inserted back during the loop?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, set

I just notice this function seems very useful for implementing DFS search algorithms.

For example, say, we know the edge to traverse a graph {{A->B}, {B->C}, {A->C}, {C->A}} and we wants to find a path over all edges: A->C->A->B

Eveytime I visiit this kind of problem, I will solve it by a DSP by having a datastructure to denote which "node/edge" has been vistied/used.

I usually just use a vector to save it and modify the value (and modify back) to simulate the node is used

For examples:

```
string now = "A";
vector<string> nexts = get_all_edges_starting_from(now);
for (int i=0; i<nexts.size(); i++) {
   string next = nexts[i];
   nexts[i] == "visited"; // assume no node named "visited"
   if (go_recursive_and_find_path_cover_all_edges())
   {
      results.push_back(now); // some global or whatever variable to store the result
      return true;
   }
   nexts[i] = next; // abandon the "visit" so the recursion can use node/edge next time
}
return false;
```

It works find, but is not efficent compared to use map or set/multiset. However, I really don't know how to traverse the map/set/multiset while the element is earsed and inserted back during the loop.

For example, a failed example might be:

```
string now = "A";
multiset<string> nexts = get_all_edges_starting_from(now);
multiset<string>::iterator it = nexts.begin();
for (it != nexts.end()) {
   string next = *(it);
   nexts.erase(next); // visited
   if (go_recursive_and_find_path_cover_all_edges())
   {
      results.push_back(now); // some global or whatever variable to store the result
      return true;
   }
   nexts.insert(next); // abandon the "visit"
   it++; 
}
return false;
```

This example will fail because I ruin the memory structure of elements by removing and adding elements inside the loop.

In general, I know it is impossible to do it because the behavior might be not defined when we consider the case of adding a "new" element before the current traversing posisiton. However, in the example of DFS, we ususally just remove element and add the element "being removed before back".

Is there a easy way of doing it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C, please pick your tags more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's not clear that a multimap is really better than a vector, because it has much worse memory locality, so please do try both implementation strategies and compare.

Next, your loop contains some basis inefficiencies that we can fix:

```
for (auto it = nexts.begin(); it != nexts.end(); )
{
    string next = *it;
    auto it = nexts.erase(it);
    if (...) { ... }
    nexts.insert(it, std::move(next));
}
```

Points of interest:

- Don't delete by value, but by iterator.
- Insert with hint, since you already know where the element goes.
- Move-insert the string, since you don't need a copy.
- In C++17 you can even move the string *out* of the map using `extract`.